# Algorithm to compare two images with pattern - Python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-2.7, scipy, computer-vision

I would like to ask you for help. I am a student and for academic research I'm designing a system where one of the modules is responsible for **comparison of low-resolution simple images** (img, jpg, jpeg, png, gif). However, I need guidance if I can write an implementation in **Python** and how to get started. Maybe someone of you met once with something like this and would be able to share their knowledge.

**Issue 1 - simple version**
The input data must be compared with the pattern (including images) and the data output will contain information about the degree of similarity (percentage), and the image of the pattern to which the given input is the most similar. In this version, the presumption is that the input image is not modified in any way (ie not rotated, tilted, etc.)

**Issue 2 - difficult version**
The input data must be compared with the pattern (including images) and the data output will contain information about the degree of similarity (percentage), and the image of the pattern to which the given input is the most similar. In this version, the presumption is that the input image can be rotated

Can some of you guys tell me what I need to do that and how to start. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you upload some example images?

Comment: Ok there are two images:
Pattern and Input

Pattern: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fsjx.jpg
Input: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xUHhB.jpg

Comment: What does it mean for two images to be 'similar'? It's entirely non-obvious to me, and I would guess that answering that question will be half your task, here.

Answer (score 0):

As a starter, you could read in the images using `matplotlib`, or the python imaging library (`PIL`).
Comparing to a pattern could be done by a cross-correlation, which you could do using `scipy`or `numpy`. As you only have few pixels, I would go for numpy which does not use fourier transforms.

```
import pylab as P
import numpy as N

# read the images    
im1 = P.imread('4Fsjx.jpg')
im2 = P.imread('xUHhB.jpg')

# do the crosscorrelation
conv = N.convolve(im1, im2)
# a measure for similarity then is:
sim = N.sum(N.flatten(conv))
```

please note, this is a very quick and dirty approach and you should spend quite some thoughts on how to improve it, not even including the rotation that you mentioned. Anyhow; this code can read in your images, and give you a measure for similarity, although the `convolve` will not work on color coded data. I hope it will give you something to start at.

Comment: I will try this fast code. Maybe first i made image monochromatic and try to clear noise on background

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start as some pseudo code.  I would strongly recommend getting numpy/scipy to help with this.

```
#read the input image:
files = glob.glob('*.templates')
listOfImages = []
for elem in files:
  imagea = scipy.misc.imread(elem)
  listOfImages.append(imagea)

#read input/test imagea
targetImage = scipy.misc.imread(targetImageName)
```

now loop through each of the listOfImages and compute the "distance"
note that this is probably the hardest part.  How will you decide
if two images are similar?  Using direct pixel comparisons?  Using
image histograms, using some image aligment metric(this would be useful 
for your difficult version). Some of the simple gotchas, I noticed that your uploaded images were different sizes.  If the images are of different sizes then you will have to 
sweep over the images.  Also, can the images be scaled?  Then you will need to either have a scale invariant metric or try the sweep over different scales

```
#keep track of the min distance
minDistance = Distance(targetImage,listOfImages[0])
minIndex = 0
for index,elem in enumerate(listOfImages):
  currentDistance = Distance(targetImage,elem)
  if currentDistance < minDistance:
    minDistance = currentDistance
    minIndex = index
```

The distance function is where the challenges are, but I'll leave that
for you.

Comment: The worst things is that i'm not graphic and i have no idea which method would be perfect (?). Another bad thing is i have no support from my teacher cause he is unavailabe till next march!!! So i'm alone. As well I'm not a programmer (I'm database administrator) so i know Python just a little bit. 
I find solution with OCR but...OCR doesn't recognise letter/digits (it will be at most letters/digits no pictures at all) properly.